# What does this error mean? android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, classcastexception

The exception message:

> android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you are trying to cast CoordinatorLayout to Toolbar.. Check in xml code to get the right id for toolbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293097/coordinatorlayout-cannot-be-cast-to-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar)

Comment: Can you please share the `app_bar_main.xml` code? Please avoid posting the screenshot as it would be difficult for code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO.

The error means exactly what it says: You're trying to use an object of type `CoordinatorLayout` as if it was a `Toolbar`-object. You need to find out where that is happening in your code, and correct it by passing the correct object.

From your screenshot, I would guess you should be able to find it by looking at the places where you're using the variable `toolbar`.

(Sounds like you're trying to create a tool-bar, but accidentally passing a layout-object to the `toolbar`-variable instead of an actual toolbar-object).

---

**PS:** If you want more help, it would be useful to include part of your code (especially the lines the exception is thrown on), and also your stack trace. You can update your question using the `edit` link below your original post.

Comment: i have added screenshots of the XMl and the .java where im calling the toolbar (toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.status_appBar); line 37). I was trying to 
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_layout" android:id="@+id/status_appBar". This gave an error so I just appMain

Answer (score 0):

ClassCastException is generated when you try to cast instance to a class of which is not an instance. Here in your case you are trying to cast your `CoordinatorLayout` to `Toolbar`. Check if you have assigned correct id in `findviewbyId()` for toolbar object.